# Equivalent geodesic rays

Tags: metric-spaces, geodesic, geometric-group-theory, hausdorff-distance

I am reading the book 'Metric spaces of non-positive curvature' by Bridson and Haefliger. In page 427 the following is said:

Two geodesic rays $c, c^\prime \colon [0, \infty)\rightarrow X$ are said to be asymptotic if $\sup_{t} d(c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is finite; this condition is equivalent to saying that the Hausdorff distance between the images of $c$ and $c^\prime$ is 
finite.

The Hausdorff distance of general subsets $A,B$ is defined as follows: $d_{H}(A,B)=\inf\{ \epsilon \mid A \subseteq N_{\epsilon}(B), B\subseteq N_{\epsilon}(A)\}$

It is clear that if $\sup_{t} d(c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is finite, the Hausdorff distance is finite.

Now assume that the Hausdorff distance is finite (say $k$) and let $t\in [0, \infty)$. Then, there exists $t^\prime \in [0, \infty)$ such that $d(c(t), c^\prime(t^\prime)) \leq k$. Hence, $d(c(t), c^\prime(t)) \leq d(c(t), c^\prime(t^\prime))+ d(c^\prime(t^\prime), c^\prime(t))\leq k+d(c^\prime(t^\prime),c^\prime(t))=k+|t-t^\prime|$.

I should find an upper bound independent of $t$ for that number, but I do not know how to proceed. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't read the book yet but so I might be missing something. But the following seems to be a good example to consider: consider $c(t)=t$ and $c'(t)=2t$ in $\mathbb{R}$. 

The hausdorff distance of their images is 0 but the $\sup_t |c(t)-c'(t)| = \infty$.

So your proof needs to use some properties of geodesic rays that are not present in this example. What other properties  of geodesic rays would help you here?

Comment: Why is in that case $c^\prime$ a geodesic ray? In order to be a geodesic, $d(c^\prime(t), c^\prime(t^\prime))$ needs to be equal to |$t-t^\prime|$, and that does not hold. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, c' is not a geodesic. I was trying to get you to realize that you need to use the property $d(c'(t),c'(t')=|t-t'|$, but I didn't see that you had already attempted to use that. Here's a better hint. You want to find an upper bound on $|t-t'|$.  If t' was much larger than t, then $c'(t')$ would be much further away from $c'(0)$ than $c(t)$ would be from $c(0)$ (draw a diagram).  Do you see why this is impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the Hausdorff distance is bounded above by $K<\infty$.

Let $C_0=|c(0)-c'(0)|$.

Fix $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we want to bound $|c(t)-c'(t)|$. 
Let $t'$ be a point for which $|c(t)-c'(t')|\leq K$.

We know that the distance from $c'(0)$ to $c'(t')$ is $t'$ because $c'$ is a geodesic.

Alternatively, we can jump from $c'(t')$ to $c(t)$, and from $c(t)$ to $c(0)$, and then finally from $c(0)$ to $c'(0)$.
The total length of this path is bounded by $K+t+C_0$.

We conclude that $t'\leq K+t+C_0$ (Formally, I am using the triangle inequality twice here).

A simlar argument shows that $t\leq K+t'+C_0$.

So $|t-t'| \leq K+C_0$.

Combine this what you've already written above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!